# How does browsers compute 'auto' value?

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, stylesheet, margin

I have two similar styles. When I viewed them in the chrome inspector they have different values although the styles applied are similar.

[image]

The margins of the elements have the 'auto' value but when computed by the browser there is a big difference between them although the width is the same.

For those who will be asking me to point it to a single stylesheet, I actually can't because the first style is for a wordpress theme and the other one is for a whmcs template.

Update:

added these two screenshots. both windows are maximized

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is not a specific value, and on a block element basically means to let the browser decide. (As in, take up remaining space). I expect **your browser window width**, or a parent element **is wider in the case where you see the larger margin** being rendered. (See the "styles" tab instead of the "computed" to see the applied styles)

When you set `auto` for both left and right margin, it will center the element. If you set `auto` only for left margin, the element will align to the right side.

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Values

Comment: Yes, that is why I am asking why it has a different value. The width is both 1170. so it should take the remaining space on both sides. Here's a screenshot of the styles tab. http://prntscr.com/2a2fmp

Comment: @kapitanluffy I see both left and right margins have the value `auto` from `bootstrap.css`. I can't really see what's wrong in that screenshot? How does the page look, does it not center the element?

Comment: If you look at the computed margin, there is a huge difference between them almost 60px. Also if the font-size is explicitly declared as 14px, it should show 14px right? take a look at this screenshot. http://prntscr.com/2a2jss

Comment: @kapitanluffy Are you having an actual issue or are you just wondering about the strangeness of computed values?

Comment: I am both having an actual issue and wondering at the same time.

Comment: you can visit the site here http://www.yourdigitalturf.com/ and the blog here http://blog.yourdigitalturf.com/

Comment: @kapitanluffy Presently, at those two links, i can see no difference in rendered margin on `.container` in the header, as long as i keep the window the same size (maximized). What is the actual issue/problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Ok that is weirder. I already cleared the cache and set the devtools not to use the cache. I added two more screenshots at the post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42866/discussion-between-xec-and-kapitanluffy)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Chrome renders it differently. Other browsers display it correctly. Only the Chrome browser in my PC displays it differently. The Chrome browser in my mobile displays it correctly so I guess it is a browser issue.