# CSS gradient background-size in Chrome / IE 11

Tags: css, google-chrome, gradient, linear-gradients

It seems that Chrome is not following the spec for interpreting the background-size property in CSS3.

Consider the following markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html {height: 100%;}
            body {height: 100%;}
            div {
                height: 100%; 
                background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,red,green,blue);
                background-size: 30%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This should place a single div which fills the view and is decorated with a rainbow gradient.  My understanding is that this gradient should be 30% of the view in width and 100% in height.

The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-size) for the background-size property states

> The first value gives the width of the corresponding image, the second value its height. If only one value is given the second is assumed to be auto.

Thus, in this case, it is as if I had declared `background-size: 30% auto`.

and

> An auto value for one dimension is resolved by using the image’s intrinsic ratio and the size of the other dimension, or failing that, using the image’s intrinsic size, or failing that, treating it as 100%.

and the [specification for gradients](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#intrinsic-dimensions) states

> The term intrinsic dimensions refers to the set of the intrinsic height, intrinsic width, and intrinsic aspect ratio (the ratio between the width and height), each of which may or may not exist for a given object... CSS gradients, defined in this specification, are an example of an object with no intrinsic dimensions at all.

Thus, auto should default to 100%, and it is as if I had declared `background-size: 30% 100%`.  Currently, declaring this specifically is how I am working around this.

This is exactly how Firefox (56.0.1) seems to display the page.

[image: Firefox capture]

However, Chrome (62.0.3202.62) does not.  It gets the width right (I may have cut a little of the edge off in the screen capture, but the rightmost repetition looks like about 10% as it should), but seems to interpret the height as also being 30%.  IE 11 looks exactly the same as the Chrome display.

[image: Chrome capture]

So, my questions:

1. Am I interpreting the specification correctly?  The newest edition (4th) of **CSS: The Definitive Guide** seems to support my interpretation as well as the page at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#compatNote_1) (which suggests that this property has changed at some point).
2. If so, is this a known bug in Chrome which is being worked on/fixed?  [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) does not list any known issues with Chrome.
3. If not, how do I go about reporting a bug in Chrome  (as there will be no IE 12, it obviously can't be fixed there, but may or may not work in Edge)?

Comment: Wondering if adding opening and closing div tags makes a diff.

Comment: @wazz What do you mean?  Replacing `<div/>` with `<div></div>`?  I just tried that, and it doesn't change the behavior (and I didn't see any reason it should've).  I'm not really looking for a work-around (I have one - explicitly declare the 100% height), but am more concerned in determining which behavior is correct according to spec, and if Chrome is wrong, making sure that gets reported and eventually fixed in a later update (and I have no idea where Chrome bugs are reported).

Comment: I understand. Was just a random thought.

Comment: MDN does specifically say, "If you use a <gradient> as the background and specify a background-size to go with it, it's best not to specify a size that uses a single auto component, or is specified using only a width value (for example, background-size: 50%). Rendering of <gradient>s in such cases changed in Firefox 8, and at present is generally inconsistent across browsers, which do not all implement rendering in full accordance with the CSS3 background-size specification and with the CSS3 Image Values gradient specification."

Comment: @wazz That is what I was referring to when I said that the site suggests that the property has changed (plus footnote 1 on the same page).  That is why I am pretty certain that I am interpreting the spec correctly (as well as the fact that the book mentioned seems to agree with me and the author is a serious authority on the subject).  However, that site refers to relatively old versions of Chrome.  I would have expected that to have been fixed by now, if it is incorrect.  Thus my second and third question (and I would have expected caniuse.com to mention the inconsistency if it is wrong).

Comment: Agreed with @wazz. If you know how to make browsers behave consistently, then by all means do so. At the end of the day, what matters is that you have a solution, not which browsers follow the specs better. It's just like all the other things where browsers have different defaults; that's why we use normalise stylesheets. Also, if there's unclarities in the specs, the wording may change in future versions anyway.

Comment: @Matthew caniuse might be a good place to make the submission about irregularities (unless they get that automatically from various places, i can't remember). for others who haven't seen the MDN article, the other thing it says is, "Note that it's particularly not recommended to use a pixel dimension and an auto dimension with a <gradient>, because it's impossible to replicate rendering in versions of Firefox prior to 8, and in browsers not implementing Firefox 8's rendering, `without knowing the exact size of the element whose background is being specified`."

Comment: "auto" doesn't equal to 100%, it does equal to the proportional value in chrome. here's another question related to that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490903/how-does-browsers-compute-auto-value

Comment: That question is in relation to auto in margins.  In the case of the `background-size` property, the spec says "An auto value for one dimension is resolved by using the image’s intrinsic ratio and the size of the other dimension, or failing that, using the image’s intrinsic size, or failing that, treating it as 100%" and states that gradients have no intrinsic ratio or size.  I believe in this case, that it should be treated as equal to 100% as Firefox interprets it.   developer.mozilla.org states that at some point the right thing was to copy the first value, but that has now changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug report filed as [Issue 711489](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711489&q=background-size%20auto&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) at the chromium bug page.  There is also a bug report filed for this with WebKit as [Bug 170834](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170834)  for the same problem.  Both reports contain a test case for the correct behavior according to the spec.